# Spring REST How to support JSON with list and object

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

is it possible to support this JSON in Spring? Without create new object in java, maybe Map?

JSON:

```
{   
    "object":"1",
    "list":[
               {
                  "id":"1"
               }
            ]
}
```

Java:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> getRecipe(@RequestBody What should I write in this place?){
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that using HashMap like below but why do you want to do that? You should create separate JavaBean class for request with properties required by REST service.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/upload/one", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> getRecipe(@RequestBody HashMap<String, Object> request){
        System.out.println(request);
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: I was curious how to do it